# Python TCP sockets headers

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I need to create a communication between a client and a server with TCP. But I'd like to send and work with "headers". So from the client I'd like to send a header "COMMAND1" and the server returns me something.

I have the following code:

Server

```
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = '0.0.0.0'
bind_port = 9998

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(5)  # max backlog of connections

print ('Listening on {}:{}'.format(bind_ip, bind_port))


def handle_client_connection(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print ('Received {}'.format(request))
    client_socket.send('Response1!'.encode('utf-8'))
    client_socket.close()

while True:
    client_sock, address = server.accept()
    print ('Accepted connection from {}:{}'.format(address[0], address[1]))
    client_handler = threading.Thread(
        target=handle_client_connection,
        args=(client_sock,)  # without comma you'd get a... TypeError: handle_client_connection() argument after * must be a sequence, not _socketobject
    )
    client_handler.start()
```

Client

```
import socket

hostname, sld, tld, port = 'www', 'integralist', 'co.uk', 80
target = '{}.{}.{}'.format(hostname, sld, tld)

# create an ipv4 (AF_INET) socket object using the tcp protocol (SOCK_STREAM)
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# connect the client
# client.connect((target, port))
client.connect(('0.0.0.0', 9998))

# send some data (in this case a HTTP GET request)
client.send('hi'.encode('utf-8'))

# receive the response data (4096 is recommended buffer size)
response = client.recv(4096)

print (response)
```

Anyone knows the best way to return "Response1!" when the header is "COMMAND1" and "Response2!" when the header is "COMMAND2"?

I can't find examples on how to use headers

EDIT: It doesn't have to be "COMMAND1" or "COMMAND2" it can be a "0" or "1", or anything else.

Comment: There is no such thing as headers in TCP. You may want to append the returns from each `recv()` into a buffer and parse the buffer to find any data you expect in order to detect which COMMAND has been sent.

Comment: @quamrana are you sure? Look at this: http://telescript.denayer.wenk.be/~hcr/cn/idoceo/images/tcp_header.gif

Comment: @VladislavZhdanov: TCP has a fixed header which serves only the purposes needed by TCP itself. You cannot add your custom headers to it. Your "headers" are application logic and thus belong into the payload.

Comment: There are no such things as headers in TCP from a programmers point of view. TCP is a stream protocol and the actual headers are invisible to the programmer.

Comment: Read the first n bytes? eg 8 for 'COMMAND1', 1 for '0'

Comment: When you say 'header' you evidently mean 'request'. Please don't make up your own terminology, or abuse existing terminology for some new purpose. Not so new in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something i have done with my program to accept such headers
Use **pickle** library to encode a dict **headers** and send it through socket.
Code will look something like this.

```
import pickle
def handleSocket(headers:dict):
   message = pickle.dumps(headers)
   socket.send(message)
```

For server side, you will be handling it
Gonna initialise the socket recv to 100 kb

```
def handleReceivedSocket(socket):
    message:dict = pickle.loads(socket.recv(102400))
```

Another way to do this. Is sending a raw json string to the server (just change **pickle.dumps**,**pickle.loads** by **json.dumps**,**json.loads**
But it will be in raw and less secure.

Last way you can do it is uri encoding. Check [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add your own header, you just have to:

1. Make sure your programm finds the start of your message (like, every message beginns "!?&")
2. Send your own header-data just after the start-symbol of your message.
3. Maybe mark the end of your message with something or pass a length in your header.
4. Since TCP will give you a stream of data, it might come to a case, where it just gives you 2 or 3 messages at once. You have to separate these messages by yourself (e.g. by using "?!&" as start of every message).

You can always create your own protocoll as payload of another protocoll. Just as TCP is just payload from the ethernet point of view.

Comment: Can you post the shortest possible server- and client-side program, which accomplishes your proposal? It sounds like it could work fine.